# JavaFX application -only the GUI works but the back-end is not working after deployment

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I was trying to package my java application (create an executable) in intelliJ. Everything works well until I generated my executable. The button on the GUI works however when I hit run, it does not do anything. The application works well in intellij environment(not making it as an executable)but not after I generate it as an executable. (Javafx 8)

Comment: There are many different things that could cause this behavior. Without seeing at least the code that you are trying to execute when the button is pressed, and preferably a [MCVE] that behaves the same way, there's really very little chance of being able to answer this question, other than just providing blind guesses.

Comment: @James_D I have added a link to my source code. I think it might be a dependency issue because my other javafx application works fine(it does not have any library). Nevertheless, I have tried various settings in intelliJ, the generated executable is still not working .

Comment: Please don't link code. If the link goes away the question becomes useless for other users. And there is really way too much code for anyone to look at there. Create the smallest project that recreates the problem, and post that directly in your question.